# Is it possible to make Remote Action Asynchronous?

Tags: visualforce, future, javascript-remoting

I have a Remote action call from my Visualforce Page.

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
           '{!$RemoteAction.PartnerPrimeSubController.calculatePartnerPrimeSub}',
            handlePartnerPrimeSubResult,
            {escape: false}
);
```

and my controller "**PartnerPrimeSubController**" looks like this

```
@RemoteAction
global static List<String> calculatePartnerPrimeSub(){
    //Custom Code
    return finalJSONData;
}
```

Is it possible to make JSRemoting Asynchronous?

I tried something like this and failed:

```
@future @RemoteAction
global static List<String> calculatePartnerPrimeSub(){
    //Custom code
}
```

**Use Case behind this requirement:**

1. I am trying to invoke 10 VF Remoting calls after DOM Load Complete in my Visualforce Page. 
       When i checked the network in chrome console, Salesforce tries to
       process 1 VF remoting call at a time.
2. Salesforce completes 1 remoting    call and 9 other VF Remoting call seems to be waiting until first remoting completes.
3. I am also trying to improve the performance of my page by moving
       away    from Action Function and implementing Lazy loading through
       VF Remoting.

Any pointers?

Comment: Do you need to make 10 separate Vf Remoting calls?  Can't you consolidate some of them?  Whats the scenario?

Comment: Each and every Remoting Call have different SOQL and different Business Logic behind it. My Visualforce page is actually a component and it is used in other pages too.

Comment: It is async, thats why the result is passed to a callback.

Comment: @phil, This is what i found in Salesforce APEX documentation: "The remote method call executes synchronously, but it doesn’t wait for the response to return. When the response returns, the callback function handles it asynchronously. "

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I guess the answer is the SF document itself. Have a look at this link http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm

You can configure your remoting call using these three parameters "**buffer**","timeout" and "escape". Usually written at the end of a call.

You have to look for the parameter "**buffer**". As per the docs **buffer** decides

> Whether to group requests executed close to each other in time into a
>   single request. The default is true.

So to make your individual call to the controller you have to set this parameter as 
"**false**"

**Example**

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
        '{!$RemoteAction.MyController.getAccount}', 
        accountName, 
        function(result, event){

        }, 
        { buffer: false, escape: true, timeout: 30000 }
    );
```

Comment: By the way remote action are always async and I guess what you want is to have a individual call.

Comment: since by default buffer=true in VF remoting, i was fooled by Chrome Network Console which appeared to be synchronous call. Thanks for clarification.