# Visualforce javascript remoting synchronous

Tags: javascript, javascript-remoting

I am using javascript remoting to get data from apex method.

My problem is javascript remoting is working Asynchronously.I want to work it as synchronously.

Please suggest me.

Answer (score 4):

By definition, VF remoting (like AJAX) is asyncrhonous. As the [official documentation](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/pages/Content/pages_js_remoting.htm) states "The remote method call executes synchronously, but it doesn’t wait for the response to return. When the response returns, the callback function handles it asynchronously."

This [link](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/18918/is-it-possible-to-make-remote-action-asynchronous) would help explain how to use the associated parameters when firing a remoting call -

Depending on what your exact use case is, you may want to handle the behavior appropriately in your callback function.

Answer (score 2):

Use the below format

```
Visualforce.remoting.Manager.invokeAction(
                '{!$RemoteAction.ControllerName.methodname}',
                var1,var2,
                function(result, event){
                    if (event.status) {
                   //all code after remote controller will be here

                }, 
                {escape: true}
            );
```